# Summation two by two of the elements of an array

Tags: python-3.x

I have a an array of 40 000 elements and I would like to add the elements two by two so that I can reduce the elements to 20 000. How can I do that. Thanks

Comment: Can you please include an example input and output?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably iterate over a range of "every other index" - in this case, that would be `for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)`, which would produce `[0, 2, 4, ..., 39996, 39998]`. From there, we just add the contents at each index to the contents of the index following it.

```
import random
my_list = random.choices(range(100), k=40000)
print(len(my_list))
# 40000

new_list = [my_list[i] + my_list[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)]
print(len(new_list))
# 20000
```

---

Another way that's a bit less efficient but doesn't have a risk of `IndexError`ing if the list has an odd number of elements, is to `zip()` two copies of the collection, using the same pattern in our slices to select only the even `[::2]` or odd `[1::2]` elements:

```
new_list = [even + odd for (even, odd) in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work for my data which look like this: [2738. 2871. 2828. ... 2810. 2721. 2806.].. More help will be appreciated.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-31de079aa57b> in <module>
----> 1 new_list = [Fluo[i] + Fluo[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(Fluo),2)]
      2 new_list

<ipython-input-43-31de079aa57b> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 new_list = [Fluo[i] + Fluo[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(Fluo),2)]
      2 new_list

IndexError: index 39999 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 39999

Comment: Your array must have an odd number of elements (it has 39999 elements, not 40000). I'll leave solving this problem as an exercise to the reader, it's not super hard.